# What does 'two-level regular expressions' mean?

Tags: regex

I understand basic regular expression, but unsure what the below quote means (regarding how to implement a wiki parser), could anyone provide some pseudo code to enlighten me?

> #### Two-level regular expressions
>
> This is a very popular approach. It's pretty fast, as it scans the raw text exactly two times.
>
> The idea is to create two kinds of regular expressions -- one to split the text into blocks of different kinds (paragraphs, headings, lists, preformatted blocks, etc.) and then process each of them with different character-level regular expression.

Quote from: http://www.wikicreole.org/wiki/CommonWikiParsingTechniques

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means not trying to accomplish multiple tasks in a single Regex, but to split it into two tasks (two levels); splitting first, then handling each token separately.

My opinion is that people often unecessarily try to have a single Regex do too much at once, instead of making things much simpler by splitting different tasks like this.

Comment: +1, I concur absolutely. Why people enjoy shooting themselves in the foot that much, I will never understand.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like "two-level regular expressions" is a (slightly ambiguous) term for something I've recommended in a few answers here on StackOverflow for parsing a slightly difficult (but still regular) language problem.

An example is getting all the `img src=` URLs from an HTML page. It's possible (but rather messy) to do this all in one regular expression; something that makes more sense is to use a regular expression to get all the `<img>` tags (capturing the whole tag), then using a different regular expression to get `src="http://some-url-here.com"` from each of the matches. This makes code far more readable and you're only scanning the text twice.

Comment: I don't know if I've ever heard the term before. I would think *two step* would be a more clear term.

Comment: Okay, maybe it's not official. :-) I don't have a name for it really. I just write it in my answers :-)